# Display exception message handled by Spring using JSP

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I'm new in Spring and also in JSP. I'm working in the project and I needed to create a page where application will be redirected in case of specific exceptions.
I have service's method which throws one of exceptions. This method is called in one of our page controller with @RequestMapping annotation. So to redirect to specific error page, I created two methods with @ExceptionHanlder which handle this exceptions in this controller. How it looks:

```
@ExceptionHandler(IllegalStateException.class)
public ModelAndView handleIllegalStateException (IllegalStateException ex) {
    ModelAndView modelAndView =  new ModelAndView("redirect:/error");
    modelAndView.addObject("exceptionMsg", ex.getMessage());
    return modelAndView;
}
```

But there wasn't enough. I also need to create ErrorPageController:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/error")
public class ErrorPageController {
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView displayErrorPage() {
        return new ModelAndView("error");
    }
}
```

And now works displaying error page. But my problem is, that I can't display error message in JSP...
I have:

```
<h3>Error page: "${exceptionMsg}"</h3>
```

But I don't see a message ;/ Instead of it, I see message in URL:

```
localhost/error?exceptionMsg=Cannot+change+participation+status+if+the+event+is+cancelled+or+it+has+ended.
```

And it's wrong because in URL I want to have only an "localhost/error" and nothing more. This message I want to display in JSP.

Comment: Because you create a new model and view with an empty model. But why do you need a custom exception handler? The default strategy included the thrown exception in a attribute called `exception`. That way it should be available to your error page. The main issue here is you are doing a redirect which trigger a new request, hence you need a controller. By default the model parameters are encoded as request parameters. In your controller handling the error don't create a new model and view, simply return "error" as the page, or declare a view-controller in your config, saves you a class.

Comment: Hmmm it works, but how to display message in JSP? And is it possible to print other URL? Because now I have URL which I opened, but I want to see or be redirected to "localhost/error". I need this because application works that way...

Comment: The `redirect` isn't the problem the problem is in the controller selecting the view, you are destroying the model with that controller (i.e making it empty). Also for a redirect you want to use the `RedirectAttributes` instead of the normal model.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To fix both of your issues (show the message, and have the proper url) you should in original code change you exception handler method to e.g.

```
@ExceptionHandler(IllegalStateException.class)
public RedirectView handleIllegalStateException(IllegalStateException ex, HttpServletRequest request) {
    RedirectView rw = new RedirectView("/error");
    FlashMap outputFlashMap = RequestContextUtils.getOutputFlashMap(request);
    if (outputFlashMap != null) {
        outputFlashMap.put("exceptionMsg", ex.getMessage());
    }
    return rw;
}
```

Why? If you want your attributes to persist through redirect, you need to add them to flash scope. The code above uses the FlashMap, from the docs

> A FlashMap is saved before the redirect (typically in the session) and
>   is made available after the redirect and removed immediately.

If it were to be a normal controller method, you could have simply added RedirectAttributes as an argument, but on @ExceptionHandler methods, the arguments of RedirectAttributes are not resolved, so you need to add the HttpServletRequest and use the RedirectView.

Answer (score 2):

You have to change `ModelAndView` to:

```
@ExceptionHandler(IllegalStateException.class)
public ModelAndView handleIllegalStateException (IllegalStateException ex) {
    ModelAndView modelAndView =  new ModelAndView("error");
    modelAndView.addObject("exceptionMsg", ex.getMessage());
    return modelAndView;
}
```

And have this part in error.jsp:

```
<h3>Error page: "${exceptionMsg}"</h3>
```

Comment: It also works, but still have the same problem with the URL... I need to have "localhost/error" URL.